# I want to pass value to multiple url in php using ajax and return the response in multiple html element id

Tags: javascript, ajax

i want to send a value to multiple url's in php using ajax.. in the example below, i want to send the request to getuser.php and getuser2.php   and want to return the response to element id TXTHINT  and TXTHINT2  .. the below code does not work .. where am i going wrong.?

```
  function showUser(str) {
      if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
      }
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?city_main="+str,true);
      xmlhttp.send();



    function showUser2(str) {
      if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint2").innerHTML="";
        return;
      }
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("txtHint2").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser2.php?city_main="+str,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }  


    }
```

Comment: could u help me with that....

Comment: if it is a copy/paste code above, you have syntax error - unclosed braces of 'showUser' function

Comment: can you give us the error message that it gives?

Comment: the function showuser2 is nested in function showuser

Comment: and why? It can't be called from any other place than from the first function... and actually there is no calling of the second function

Comment: i thought since the showUser2 function is nested it will be called automatically ... so how do i do it?

Comment: the function is not called until you call it... see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33384149/2346285)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead of you code (yours is really ugly and the nesting is weird):

```
function fillHint(hintID, url, str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById(hintID).innerHTML="";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById(hintID).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET",url+".php?city_main="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function showUser(str) {
  fillHint("txtHint", "getuser", str);
}

function showUser2(str) {
  fillHint("txtHint2", "getuser2", str);
}

function someMasterCallFn() {
  if (...) { // if first should be called
    showUser(theString);
  } else if (...) { // if second should be called
    showUser2(theString);
  }
}
```

And if you want to call both functions you have two possibilities:

```
function showUser(str) {
  fillHint("txtHint", "getuser", str);
  showUser2(str);
}

function showUser2(str) {
  fillHint("txtHint2", "getuser2", str);
}
```

or

```
function someMasterCallFn() {
  showUser(theString);
  showUser2(theString);
}
```